# Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^2 \sum^n_{k=1} {1 \over {(n^2+k^2)^2}}$ using Riemann sums

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, riemann-sum

> Find
>   $$\lim_{n \to \infty} n^2 \sum^n_{k=1} {1 \over {(n^2+k^2)^2}}$$
>   using Riemann sums.

I got

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n^2 \sum^n_{k=1} {1 \over {(n^2+k^2)^2}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum^n_{k=1} {1 \over {n^2}} {1 \over {(1+({k \over n})^2)^2}} $$

Now, this is not the classic $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum^n_{k=1} {1 \over {n}} {1 \over {1+({k \over n})^2}}$ that I can just define $f(x)={1 \over {1+x^2}}$. The summation is to $n$ and not $n^2$... what should I do?

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n b_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \cdot \lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$ when both  $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$ exists. Can you use this?

Comment: @Winther so it is $\int^1_0 {1 \over {1+x^2}}dx = \arctan \biggl|^1_0 = {\pi \over 4}$. so it's ${\pi ^2 \over 16}$?
but in the answer below someone wrote 0... =\

Comment: First of all the function is $\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}$. Secondly, what I meant is that $\frac{1}{n^2}\sum^n f(k/n) = \frac{1}{n} \times \left[\frac{1}{n}\sum^n f(k/n)\right]$. The second factor is a Riemann sum that converges to an integral and the first factor converges to zero.

Comment: @Winther yeah, my bad

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n^2 \sum^n_{k=1} {1 \over {(n^2+k^2)^2}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{k=1} {1 \over {n}} {1 \over {(1+({k \over n})^2)^2}}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum^n_{k=1} {1 \over {n}} {1 \over {(1+({k \over n})^2)^2}}=0\times\int_{0}^1\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}=0 $$

Comment: The denominator of the next-to-last  line is nonsensical.

Comment: The second to last equality isn't quite right... You can't take half a limit. You took the limit in the numerator but not in the denominator. You should use the fact that the limit of the sum is bounded, then you'll get what you want just as quickly.

Comment: I fixed it,  thank you very much